# Folder with files shows as empty

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Last night I create a new project in Visual Studio 2010, in the folder `c:\development\hobby\devices`.  When I navigate to that folder in a new instance of Windows Explorer, I get the 'This folder is empty.' message in the files pane.

If I then, from within Visual Studio, issue the "Open containing folder command", explorer opens to the folder `c:\development\hobby\devices\LoopBack`, where loopback is a project under the main folder.  If I paste that path into another new instance of explorer, explorer correctly opens `c:\development\hobby\devices`.

How is this possible?

Comment: Please add the solution as Answer and accept it so the question will be marked as Solved..

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what comes of typing paths instead of selecting them.  Some elementary detective work yielded the following interesting results:

```
C:\>dir dev*.
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is E4B4-0563

 Directory of C:\

2010/11/28  09:20 PM    <DIR>          Development
2010/12/01  08:57 PM    <DIR>          Develpment
2010/11/02  06:31 PM    <DIR>          DevTools
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  63 965 368 320 bytes free
```

Where my disappearing project was in the badly spelt one.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, something similar happened to me a few weeks ago, a reboot fixed it.
But mine was a secondary drive and i assume it had some mounting issues

Answer (score 0):

Obvious question: do you have Explorer set to show hidden files?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Show-hidden-files

(Same procedure works for 7.)

Comment: Yes, but it this case all files are invisible, in one version of the cat, and on the other, they are all visible.  The decider is how I open the folder in windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to attrib command through the command prompt on the desired folder. I think it will help. you. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx) is tutorial how to use the command even it shows the read only attribute so in same way you can remove hidden attribute by typing -h. You can use the command `-r -h -s drive:folder path` at the same time. Best of luck.